# Is it possible to convert the type of a Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built a train station in the "redstone-ready" superflat world preset, and I was wondering if I could change the world type so all new chunks are normal world chunks, instead of superflat chunks. I don't want the train to just run through a superflat world, it is too boring.

Is this possible? If so, how would one go about doing it?

Comment: This might help you out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0G5BkHlC5Q

Comment: @Allov That's not quite what I wanted, but it did give me the idea for using NBTEdit, which has solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by editing my world's `level.dat` with **NBTExplorer**, changing the variable `generatorType` from `flat` to `default`.