# Change existing world to superflat (server)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a default generated world and I created a few things in it. I want it to become superflat and I don't want to loose any progress I made in the world. Is that possible ? I've seen the opposite [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97826/is-it-possible-to-convert-the-type-of-a-minecraft-world) but I can't find the `generatorType` variable in my `level.dat` .

Comment: With the way Minecraft works, changing the world's generator for a superflat setting will only have an effect of new chunks of land. So all of your existing world will remain the same, the superflat areas will only be the new lands you discover in your world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could actually be `generatorName`. You may also need to set `generatorOptions` to one of the [SuperFlat preset](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#Customization).

[image: A screenshot of NBTExplorer]

---

**Edit:**

Just tried that (`generatorOptions = 2;7,2x3,2;1;village`) on client and this happened near the spawn point:

[image: Changing default world type to superflat...]

It's probably because I save and quit too early... lol

---

Wow

[image]

Comment: now I have squids keep falling down...

Comment: The problem seems to be that changing the generator changes the new chunks, no? Not the existing ones. This, or you got the wrong parameters for the generator :P

Comment: @Gnoupi because I basically just create the work, then in one second I press `Esc` -> `Save and Quit`, probably the game hasn't yet generated all the visible chunks... And I would really encourage using a superflat preset which has a ground level of 64.

Comment: ah, that explains indeed. You have parts which are made with the initial (random) generator, before you saved and changed it.

Comment: Sing to the tune of "raindrops keep falling on my head": "Squids keep falling in my world".