# Can I make my already created and edited superflat bigger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a city with a river, a forest, and a lot of buildings. But when I made it I didn't know about presets, so it has the predetermined height of a superflat: 4. Can I add more stone below with NBTexplorer or whatever so the world is bigger, but my building are still on the upper layer?

Comment: I believe you can use NBTExplorer / NBTEdit to change the preset for future chunk generation, but must use MCEdit to manually move the buildings up and add more stone in already-generated chunks.

Comment: (Note that I'm only just familiar with the capabilities of the tools—I have no experience using them for major surgery like this so I can't give practical advice in an actual answer. Just: yes, that should be possible.)

Comment: To change the superflat preset you may refer to this answer (you still need to use MCEdit to change the existing chunks): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/98706/38938

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the easiest to create more world below what you already have, you must make a new superflat world with the extended stone below and copy what you have over with MCEdit or another program like that (I am not too familiar). The world should remain intact and you should have the desired space below you to build.